# Open another activity when nfc discovered

Tags: java, android-studio, android-activity, nfc

I'm trying to create an application that, when nfc tag is discovered, launches another activity, but it's still not working.

Please let me know what I am doing wrong and how to fix it.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private NfcAdapter nfcAdapter;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        nfcAdapter = NfcAdapter.getDefaultAdapter(this);
        if (nfcAdapter == null) {
            // NFC is not supported on this device
            return;
        }

        PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(this, 0,
                new Intent(this, getClass()).addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_SINGLE_TOP), 0);
        IntentFilter[] filters = new IntentFilter[] {
                new IntentFilter(NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED),
        };
        String[][] techList = new String[][] {
                new String[] { NfcF.class.getName() }
        };
        nfcAdapter.enableForegroundDispatch(this, pendingIntent, filters, techList);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onPause() {
        super.onPause();
        nfcAdapter.disableForegroundDispatch(this);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onNewIntent(Intent intent) {
        super.onNewIntent(intent);
        if (NfcAdapter.ACTION_NDEF_DISCOVERED.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            Intent nfcIntent = new Intent(this, MainActivity2.class);
            nfcIntent.putExtra("nfcTag", intent.getParcelableExtra(NfcAdapter.EXTRA_TAG));
            startActivity(nfcIntent);
        }
    }
}
```